# Apply Display to Certain nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to display all nth-child with the value less than or equal to 4. Is there an if statement for CSS that will apply on the condition I want to display?

Thanks

Comment: There's no selector for less than or greater than. However you can use a comma separated list. For example div:nth-child(1), div:nth-child(2), div:nth-child(3), div:nth-child(4).

Comment: @AndrewNgo Yes, there is. Look at answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `:nth-child` accepts an `n` parameter which will take all non-negative integer values.

```css
:nth-child(-n+4)
```

- `n=0`: selects 4th child
- `n=1`: selects 3th child
- `n=2`: selects 2nd child
- `n=3`: selects 1st child
- `n>3`: nothing

Example:

```css
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
div:nth-child(-n+4) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
```

Comment: This is genius. Never think of that.

Comment: How about the reverse of it since my question is about "displaying" the first four child and the rest will be not displayed? @Oriol

Comment: @Alen The opposite would be `:nth-child(n+5)`. Alternatively, you can always negate with `:not`, i.e. `:not(:nth-child(-n+4))`.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use **[:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)** to achieve this.

*E.g. This will select all first **four** children of `li`s inside of `ul`*

```css
ul > li:nth-child(-n+4)
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
  <li> 5 </li>
  <li> 6 </li>
  <li> 7 </li>
</ul>
```